# Test Class not working (Case/Event)

Tags: apex, unit-test, case, event

I need Test Class to test the standard functionality :

When you change a record’s owner, some items that are related to the record are also transferred to the new owner.

In my case
Case owner changed to 'Y' => Event owner changed to 'Y'
You can check the documentation here : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_owner_transfer.htm&type=5

My issue is when i execute the test class, the owner of the event doesn't change.
Below my TestClass :
(i'll get the users from my org)

```
@isTest
private class EventTest {
    @isTest
    static void ownerEventChangedTest(){
        User[] user1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Username='YYYYY1' LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('***** user1 : ' + JSON.serializePretty(user1));

        System.runAs(user1[0]){
            User[] user2 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Username='YYYYY2' LIMIT 1];
            System.debug('***** user2 : ' + JSON.serializePretty(user2));
            
            // Create Case
            Case[] cases = new Case[]{};
            for(Integer i=0; i<1; i++){
                cases.add(new Case());
            }
            insert cases;
            System.debug('***** cases before update : ' + JSON.serializePretty(cases));
            
            // Create Event
            Event[] events = new Event[]{};
            for(Integer i=0; i<1; i++){
                events.add(new Event(WhatId = cases[0].Id, 
                                     StartDateTime = Date.today().addDays(2), // Future Event
                                     DurationInMinutes = 60));
            }
            insert events;
            System.debug('***** events inserted : ' + JSON.serializePretty(events));
            
            // Update Event with a new Owner (user2)
            Case[] caseToUpdate = new Case[]{};
            for(Case c : [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id IN : cases]){
                if(!user2.isEmpty()){
                    System.debug('***** inside for old Owner: ' + JSON.serializePretty(c.OwnerId));
                    System.debug('***** inside for new Owner : ' + JSON.serializePretty(user2[0].Id));
                    c.OwnerId = user2[0].Id;
                    caseToUpdate.add(c);
                }
            }
            
            // Update the case
            Test.startTest();
            update caseToUpdate;
            Test.stopTest();
            
            // Get the new Owner
            String newCaseOwner = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case LIMIT 1].OwnerId;
            System.debug('***** case after update : ' + JSON.serializePretty([SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case]));
            
            // Get Events
            Event[] events2 = [SELECT Id, Owner.Name, OwnerId, WhatId, StartDateTime, EndDateTime FROM Event];
            System.debug('***** event after update of the Case : ' + JSON.serializePretty(events2));
            
            // Check if new owner of Event is the owner of the Case 
            // ===> 
            // The owner of the Event IS NOT changed
            System.assertEquals(newCaseOwner, events2[0].OwnerId, 'Wrong Owner');
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea please?

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that the Events under the Case get auto transferred to the new owner. It doesn't seem to auto transfer the events in a manual case ownership change either.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/3NLqNmX
for open activities it's the case

Comment: I see. I think it's due to the definition of "Open Activities". When an Event is created, it goes directly into the "Activity History" related list, which means an Event is completed already. Event doesn't seem to have a Status field. Therefore, I would assume all events are not "Open Activities".

Comment: In the code i have : StartDateTime = Date.today().addDays(2), // Future Event
                                     DurationInMinutes = 60)); 
So it's a future event => open activity

Comment: My bad not noticing that. You are right. When the Start date is set to the future, it is shown in the "Open Activities" related table. But for some reason, the manual Case owner change doesn't auto transfer the events. I'd say if it does not do what the documentation says, it is a bug.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.
i will create a support case.